# Is it possible to use a list of items in a SELECT without using a temporary table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, temp-tables, mysql-5.6

I have the following MySQL query:

```
create temporary table if not exists temp_terms(
    term varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    soundexterm varchar(4) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO temp_terms VALUES ('brocoli', Soundex('brocoli')), ('rice', Soundex('rice')), ('aple', Soundex('aple'));

SELECT tt.term, rt.description, rt.soundex
FROM realtable rt
JOIN ( SELECT term, soundexterm FROM temp_terms ) t on tt.soundexterm = rt.soundex;

drop temporary table if exists temp_terms;
```

Which returns a result that looks like:

```
term, description, soundex
brocoli, Broccoli, B624
aple, Apple, A140
brocoli, Bresaola, B624
rice, Rusks, R200
```

Is there a way to do the same query but using the list of values instead of creating a temporary table and inserting the list values into the table?

The MySQL version I'm querying against is 5.6

Comment: Then `SELECT` and `UNION ALL` in sub-query..

Comment: @PM77-1 - This is the direction I took. Just added parameterized select statements for each term with a UNION between them.

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to go with `UNION` like so:

```
SELECT 'rice',description, soundex
FROM realtable 
WHERE soundex = Soundex('rice')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'aple',description, soundex
FROM realtable 
WHERE soundex = Soundex('aple')
UNION ALL
SELECT 'brocoli',description, soundex
FROM realtable 
WHERE soundex = Soundex('brocoli');
```

In my C# code, should anyone care, I just do the following to build the query:

```
await using var cmd = _connection.CreateCommand();
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (var i = 0; i < lookupTerms.Count; i++)
{
    sb.Append(i == lookupTerms.Count - 1
        ? $"SELECT @t{i}, description, soundex FROM realtable WHERE soundex = Soundex(@t{i});"
        : $"SELECT @t{i}, description, soundex FROM realtable WHERE soundex = Soundex(@t{i}) UNION ");
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter
    {
        ParameterName = $"@t{i}",
        DbType = DbType.String,
        Value = lookupTerms[i],
    });
}
cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
```